Error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fbec8a000 after creating and mem-mapping drm device dumb buffer with IOCTL DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB
When I execute the following function, after mmap returns, I get a kernel mapped pointer returned but its not accessible. All functions returns 0 so succeeds without errors. The offset value is set to 4311556096 after DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB IOCTL is returned and this gets passed as part of mmap offset args.
I am working with a arm64 device with kernel version 4.19.0, libdrm.so.2.4.0. The
(gdb) p *fb
$5 = {
  fd = 0,
  buffer_id = 41,
  res_x = 0,
  res_y = 0,
  data = 0x7fbec8a000 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fbec8a000>,
  size = 0,
  dumb_framebuffer = {
    height = 1080,
    width = 1920,
    bpp = 32,
    flags = 0,
    handle = 1,
    pitch = 7680,
    size = 8294400
  },
  crtc = 0x55594b23f0,
  connector = 0x0,
  resolution = 0x0
}


(gdb) p mreq
$3 = {
  handle = 1,
  pad = 0,
  offset = 4311556096


(gdb) p *connector
$6 = {
  connector_id = 37,
  encoder_id = 36,
  connector_type = 11,
  connector_type_id = 1,
  connection = DRM_MODE_CONNECTED,
  mmWidth = 480,
  mmHeight = 270,
  subpixel = DRM_MODE_SUBPIXEL_UNKNOWN,
  count_modes = 32,
  modes = 0x55594b2d30,
  count_props = 4,
  props = 0x55594b2ce0,
  prop_values = 0x55594b2d00,
  count_encoders = 1,
  encoders = 0x55594b35c0
}


Ofcourse the returned mem-mapped region is not useable. I believe the returned pointer is in the heap, the stack pointer is around 0x7ffffffd97.

(gdb) p connector_name
$9 = 0x7ffffffd97 "HDMI-A-1

I would like to see if anybody knows anything about this. Thanks.
int get_framebuffer(const char *dri_device, const char *connector_name, struct framebuffer *fb,
                    int selected_resolution)
{
    int err;
    int fd;
    drmModeResPtr res;
    drmModeEncoderPtr encoder = 0;

    /* Open the dri device /dev/dri/cardX */
    fd = open(dri_device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Could not open dri device %s\n", dri_device);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    /* Get the resources of the DRM device (connectors, encoders, etc.)*/
    res = drmModeGetResources(fd);
    if (!res) {
        printf("Could not get drm resources\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    /* Search the connector provided as argument */
    drmModeConnectorPtr connector = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < res->count_connectors; i++) {
        char name[32];

        connector = drmModeGetConnectorCurrent(fd, res->connectors[i]);
        if (!connector)
            continue;

        snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%s-%u", connector_type_name(connector->connector_type),
                 connector->connector_type_id);

        if (strncmp(name, connector_name, sizeof(name)) == 0)
            break;

        drmModeFreeConnector(connector);
        connector = 0;
    }

    if (!connector) {
        printf("Could not find matching connector %s\n", connector_name);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    if (connector->count_modes <= 0) {
        printf("No modes found for connector %s\n", connector_name);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    /* Get the resolution */
    drmModeModeInfoPtr resolution = 0;
    if (selected_resolution >= 0 && selected_resolution < connector->count_modes) {
        resolution = &connector->modes[selected_resolution];
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < connector->count_modes; i++) {
            drmModeModeInfoPtr res = 0;
            res = &connector->modes[i];
            if (res->type & DRM_MODE_TYPE_PREFERRED)
                resolution = res;
        }
    }
    if (!resolution) {
        printf("Could not find preferred resolution, use first possible resolution\n");
        resolution = &connector->modes[0];
    }

    fb->dumb_framebuffer.height = resolution->vdisplay;
    fb->dumb_framebuffer.width = resolution->hdisplay;
    fb->dumb_framebuffer.bpp = 32;

    err = ioctl(fd, DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB, &fb->dumb_framebuffer);
    if (err) {
        printf("Could not create dumb framebuffer (err=%d)\n", err);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    err = drmModeAddFB(fd, resolution->hdisplay, resolution->vdisplay, 24, 32,
            fb->dumb_framebuffer.pitch, fb->dumb_framebuffer.handle, &fb->buffer_id);
    if (err) {
        printf("Could not add framebuffer to drm (err=%d)\n", err);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    encoder = drmModeGetEncoder(fd, connector->encoder_id);
    if (!encoder) {
        printf("Could not get encoder\n");
        err = -EINVAL;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    /* Get the crtc settings */
    fb->crtc = drmModeGetCrtc(fd, encoder->crtc_id);

    struct drm_mode_map_dumb mreq;

    memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(mreq));
    mreq.handle = fb->dumb_framebuffer.handle;

    err = drmIoctl(fd, DRM_IOCTL_MODE_MAP_DUMB, &mreq);
    if (err) {
        printf("Mode map dumb framebuffer failed (err=%d)\n", err);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    fb->data = mmap(0, fb->dumb_framebuffer.size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, mreq.offset);
    if (fb->data == MAP_FAILED) {
        err = errno;
        printf("Mode map failed (err=%d)\n", err);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    /* Make sure we are not master anymore so that other processes can add new framebuffers as well */
    drmDropMaster(fd);

    fb->fd = fd;
    fb->connector = connector;
    fb->resolution = resolution;

cleanup:
    /* We don't need the encoder and connector anymore so let's free them */
    if (encoder)
        drmModeFreeEncoder(encoder);

    if (err)
        release_framebuffer(fb);

    return err;
}





The mem-mapped region returned from the mmu should be an accessible pointer.
